# Vue Script Setup Appears To Be Causing Firebase And Vuex Store Issues

Tags: firebase, vue.js, fullcalendar, vuex, vite

I'm building a small, project, app that utilises a few libraries, including the following:

- Vue (specifically Vue 3)
- Vuex (for store and state management)
- Vite
- Firebase (Auth and Firestore)
- Fullcalendar (probably not relevant for my issue but worth noting)

In my Vuex store I am running an async action that pulls an entire collection of "events" from my Firestore database and keeping it as an array in the store. This is then passed to the component that stores the calendar, where the calendar then will render based on this store array.

When I try this in the app however, one of two things happens:

1. The array does not pull through any data
2. The array does pull through but the rest of the app doesn't load

I think this is to do with the way `<script setup>` works in Vue3. The reason I think this is because if the array doesn't load in the main app but I still run a v-for in the template, the data pulls through.

Here's my code and some images of what's happening to give you all a better idea:

```
<template>
  <div class="page" v-shadow="2">
    <div class="cal" v-shadow="1">
      <p v-for="event in eventsImport">{{ event }}</p>
      <FullCalendar :options="calendarOptions" />
    </div>
    <div class="under">
      <div class="considerations" v-shadow="1">
        <ui-table fullwidth>Considerations</ui-table>
      </div>
      <div class="completions" v-shadow="1">
        <ui-table fullwidth>Completions</ui-table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
//Imports
import '@fullcalendar/core/vdom';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue3';
import timeGrid from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';
import { computed } from 'vue';

//Dispatch Store
const store = useStore();
store.dispatch('getEvents');

//Fetch Events
const eventsImport = computed(() => store.getters.events);

//Push imported events into events array 
const events = [];
eventsImport.value.forEach((event) => events.push(event));
console.log(`Events Array: ${events}`);

//Calendar Options
const calendarOptions = {
  plugins: [timeGrid, interactionPlugin],
  initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
  slotMinTime: '07:00:00',
  slotMaxTime: '18:00:00',
  weekends: false,
  locale: 'en-GB',
  contentHeight: 'auto',
  height: 'auto',
  editable: true,
  eventStartEditable: true,
  selectable: true,
  events: eventsImport,
};
</script>
```

This results in the following:

[Array Not Working - V-For Is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S7OH.png)

The image shows the V-for is loading the events as they should be into the DOM but the events array itself is not receiving anything.

After a lot of brainstorming I came to the conclusion that the app is leading before the data is fetched from the store so I put `await` in front of the dispatch (`await store.dispatch('getEvents');`) to see if this would solve the issue and whilst it does solve the events array issue, the rest of the component no longer loads.

[Array Working - Component Not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEJPy.png)

I'm at a bit of a loss now. In my head I'm pretty sure this is to do with the way the `<script setup>` compiles, where the app is not getting a chance to get the data but the template section is (hence the v-for working) but I don't know how to really fix it.

Apologies that this is a long post, I'm new and not sure how much information is needed so I decided the more detailed I can be, the better.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this for me.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be the same in any other kind of component. You do asynchronous getEvents call and don't wait before accessing results. `await` turns a component into asynchronous one and requires to use <suspense>, it won't render without it. If you're not sure how script setup works (which is syntax sugar with obscure logic) I'd suggest to stick to regular setup function before all issues are sorted out, it's well-documented.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do async tasks inside the setup function you should do it in one of the lifecycle hooks and not on root level. It is possible on top level but experimental right now: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#top-level-await

So I recommend you to do something like this in your setup function:

```
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
...
onMounted(async () => {
   await store.dispatch('getEvents');
   const eventsImport = computed(() => store.getters.events);
   const events = [];
   eventsImport.value.forEach((event) => events.push(event));
   console.log(`Events Array: ${events}`);
});
```